# Drawing the MS Paint Triangle tool using HTML5 Canvas and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I'm new at javascript and Canvas and wanted to know how to draw triangles on the canvas by clicking and dragging the mouse like we do in MS Paint, where the size of the triangle depends on how much the user drags.

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, then you should probably start by learning to draw **anything** in canvas. Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes) for tutorials and get back when you have some actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point:

```js
//HTML elements
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//Current unconnected points
var mouse = [];
//Existing triangles
var triangles = [];
//The function that draws
function draw() {
    //Clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //Draw existing triangles
    for (var tIndex = 0; tIndex < triangles.length; tIndex++) {
      var triangle = triangles[tIndex];
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(triangle.a.x, triangle.a.y);
      ctx.lineTo(triangle.b.x, triangle.b.y);
      ctx.lineTo(triangle.c.x, triangle.c.y);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    //Draw current mouse points
    if (mouse.length > 0) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(mouse[0].x, mouse[0].y);
    }
    if (mouse.length > 1) {
      ctx.lineTo(mouse[1].x, mouse[1].y);
    }
    if (mouse.length > 0) {
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
  //Catch point
canvas.onclick = function eventHandler(event) {
  //Add points to list
  mouse.push({
    x: event.layerX,
    y: event.layerY
  });
  //If we have enough points, add a triangle
  if (mouse.length >= 3) {
    //Adding the triangle
    triangles.push({
      a: mouse[0],
      b: mouse[1],
      c: mouse[2]
    });
    //Clear points
    mouse = [];
  }
  //Update canvas
  draw();
};
```

```css
body,
html,
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#canvas {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

You will have to invent drag-effects yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//HTML elements
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//Current unconnected points
var mouse = [];
//Existing triangles
var triangles = [];
//The function that draws
function draw() {
    //Clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //Draw existing triangles
    for (var tIndex = 0; tIndex < triangles.length; tIndex++) {
      var triangle = triangles[tIndex];
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(triangle.a.x, triangle.a.y);
      ctx.lineTo(triangle.b.x, triangle.b.y);
      ctx.lineTo(triangle.c.x, triangle.c.y);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    //Draw current mouse points
    if (mouse.length > 0) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(mouse[0].x, mouse[0].y);
    }
    if (mouse.length > 1) {
      ctx.lineTo(mouse[1].x, mouse[1].y);
    }
    if (mouse.length > 0) {
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
  //Catch point
canvas.onclick = function eventHandler(event) {
  //Add points to list
  mouse.push({
    x: event.layerX,
    y: event.layerY
  });
  //If we have enough points, add a triangle
  if (mouse.length >= 3) {
    //Adding the triangle
    triangles.push({
      a: mouse[0],
      b: mouse[1],
      c: mouse[2]
    });
    //Clear points
    mouse = [];
  }
  //Update canvas
  draw();
};
```

```css
body,
html,
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#canvas {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```